# How to use variable from dialogflow in activechat? Payload?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, payload

I am currently trying to use NLP (Dialogflow) to resolve all inputs into a number value. I would then like to use that number value as a variable in activechat, a visual chatbot builder. How can I do that?

EDIT: Is it done by using a payload?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using direct Dialogflow integration all entity values are accessible in Activechat as $_nlp_entity_[entity_name] variables. So, if you have @city entity in Dialogflow, when any intent with that entity triggers an event in Activechat, $_nlp_entity_city will be populated with the value for that entity.

Hope that helps.